# Showing the external direct product of U group is not cyclic

Tags: finite-groups, cyclic-groups, direct-product

> Question:
>
> Let p and q be odd primes and m and n be positive integers.
> Explain why $U\left ( p^{m} \right ) \bigoplus U\left ( q^{n} \right )$ is not cyclic.

Note that $U\left ( n \right )$-group is the group of integers less than and relatively prime to n.

Recall that $U\left ( p^{n} \right )\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}-p^{n-1}}$.

Then, $U\left ( p^{m} \right ) \bigoplus U\left ( p^{n} \right ) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{m}-p^{m-1}} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{q^{n}-q^{n-1}}$.

$\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ can be generated by 1 so this is a cyclic group. Following this, both $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{m}-p^{m-1}}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{q^{n}-q^{n-1}}$ are finite cyclic group.

Clearly, the order of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{m}-p^{m-1}} is p^{2m-1}$ and the order of $\mathbb{Z}_{q^{n}-q^{n-1}}$ is $q^{2n-1}$

It suffices for me to show that the orders are relatively prime.

Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You miscalculated the orders of these groups. And on the contrary, you don't want to show that they're relatively prime, because then it would be cyclic. You want to show that they have a common divisor

Comment: Obviously the order of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{m}-p^{m-1}}$ is $p^{m}-p^{m-1}$

Comment: Yes! There was a typo. I ought to show they are not rel. Prime

Comment: Then obviously $2$ is a common factor.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\left|U\left ( p^{m} \right )\right| = p^{m-1} (p-1)$ and $\left|U\left ( q^{n} \right )\right| = q^{n-1} (q-1)$ by totient.

Since $p$ and $q$ are odd primes, their orders are both even. Let the orders be $2h$ and $2k$ respectively, where $h$ and $k$ are positive integers.

For the sake of a contradiction, assume that $U\left ( p^{m} \right ) \bigoplus U\left ( q^{n} \right )$ is generated by $(a,b)$.

The order of $a$ must be $2h$, and the order of $b$ must be $2k$, meaning that the order of $(a,b)$ is $2\gcd(h,k)$.

Notice that $(a,b^2)$ is not a power of $(a,b)$. For if $(a,b)^m = (a,b^2)$, then $m=2hr$ and $m=2ns+1$, so $m$ is both even and odd, a contradiction.

Since $(a,b^2)$ is not a power of $(a,b)$, $(a,b)$ is not a generator of $U\left ( p^{m} \right ) \bigoplus U\left ( q^{n} \right )$, which is hence not cyclic.